# Oracle ords: How to create put/post method with collection

Tags: json, oracle, post, put, oracle-ords

I created a post method to receive the geolocation data of customers:
[Post method](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T6N0Y.png)

When I call the post method with the JSON:

```
{"customer": 1, "latitude":-21.13179, "longitude":-47.736782 }
```

my PL/SQL Script works.

Now I'd like to send a group of records but I don't know how to do it.
I created a PUT method to receive a collections of geolocations and I constructed a script just to parse the parameter:
[Put method](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CTQDw.png)

When I call the put method with the JSON:

```
{  
   "items":[  
      {  
         "customer":1,
         "latitude":-21.13179,
         "longitude":-47.736782
      },
      {  
         "customer":1,
         "latitude":-21.13179,
         "longitude":-47.736782
      }
   ]
}
PL/SQL code:

declare
l_values apex_json.t_values;
begin
apex_json.parse (
           p_values => l_values,
           p_source => :items );
end;
```

I received the message:

> ```
> 400 - Bad Request - Expected a value but got: START_ARRAY.
> ```

What I'm doing of wrong?
I want to create a post/put method to receive a collection.
Thanks for your help.

Comment: Can you please post your PL/SQL code?

Comment: Sorry, I showed the code in the image: declare
l_values apex_json.t_values;
begin
apex_json.parse (
           p_values => l_values,
           p_source => :items );
end;

Answer (score 1):

[There is an example in OracleBase](https://oracle-base.com/articles/misc/oracle-rest-data-services-ords-restful-web-services-handling-complex-json-payloads#create-api-json-table-12c) that shows a way to use 'JSON_Table' in 12c and 'JSON_Obect_t' pl/sql in 12Cr2. The JSON data is passed as a blob to the stored proc which then parses and updates/whatever. I have not tested it yet but it looks like a good approach to deal with collections which apparently cannot be handled by ORDS "out of the box". I had experimented with using the bulkload approach to load a temp table but it was for csv only and a bit tedious. Here's [Jeff Smiths blog post on that](https://www.thatjeffsmith.com/archive/2017/09/bulk-load-an-oracle-table-from-csv-via-rest/)

I have not tested this yet, I rebuilt my approach to send each entry individually but eventually I'll need to use this. I'll update this answer when I do with examples.

Answer (score 0):

I am facing the same issue and the reason would be what is posted in the below URL.

https://community.oracle.com/thread/2182167?start=0&tstart=0

"In APEX Listener 1.1 the PL/SQL Hander will automatically convert JSON properties to implicit parameters. Note this will only work for simple JSON objects, arrays or nested object are not supported."

Basically - one can't pass collections/arrays. I'm not sure if this has changed now or if there are any plans to change this in the roadmap.